# jQuery flot dates of the last days

Tags: jquery, date, charts, flot

I am trying to show the last xx days in my chart but how can i do this? I have made a jsFiddle so you guys can see what i have now.

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFAx4/)

Here is my JS code:

```
$("table.chart-dates").each(function() {
    var colors = [];
    $("table.chart-dates thead th:not(:first)").each(function() {
        colors.push($(this).css("color"));
    });
    $(this).graphTable({
        series: 'columns',
        position: 'replace',
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        colors: colors
    }, {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d/%m"
        },
        yaxis: {
            max: null,
            autoscaleMargin: 0.02
        }
    });
});​
```

I hope somewone can help me with this.

Comment: not quite following what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: What you have doesn't seem to be anything to do with your question - your table has x values of 1-5, do you want those to be something else?  The last 5 days from when?  Today?

Comment: Hi, i want to show the last 5 days yes. If i put a date like 04/04 inside it then it will not be visible in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/graphTable)? Looks like you can send a dataStart param. I created a fork to your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vansimke/G3wfB/) with the number '3' hardcoded as the start index. You would have to derive this from the logic in your program, but should get you what you want (If I am understanding your question).

Comment: Hi Vansimke, i want in the xasis that the last days are displayed. How can i do that?